# What happened to Angel Dust at the end?

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool

At the end of Deadpool, when Deadpool & Francis (a.k.a Ajax) are fighting and the boat is falling apart, everything comes down... You see Colossus carrying Negasonic Teenage Warhead (from the X-men team) & Angel Dust (from Team-Francis, the strong bad women), bringing them to safety.

In the next scene you see Francis jumping on Deadpool for the final fight.
When the fight is over, Vanessa and Deadpool start chatting while Negasonic & Colossus are watching. But where did Angel Dust go?

**Q:** Did Colossus arrest her or did he totally forget about Angel Dust and she ran off or did she die? Or what really happened to Angel Dust at the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assumption is that Colossus, the big boy scout he is, would be doing the same thing for Angel Dust, an evil mutant, as he had planned for Deadpool and Francis at the beginning, er middle of the movie. He would take them to have a talk with Xavier, who would then decide on a course of action. It's also possible that Colossus let her escape by being distracted with Deadpool, like he did with Francis.

There is no evidence from production staff after the movie's release, at this time, about where she ended up.

Answer (score 2):

It's never explicitly made clear in the movie. The general assumption is that Colossus finds a way to restrain her until he can turn her over to the authorities.

Comment: Did you just think of this answer or find it anywhere?

Comment: @Decypher As I said, it's just a general assumption. Most people that I have talked to about this will say something similar and a google search will yield similar results. It's a general assumption. No need to source those :O

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more likely that she escaped. Colossus had a tendency to make snap decisions and underestimate people. For instance when he hand cuffs Deadpool he didn't think he'd cut his hand off to get away but why wouldn't he? Colossus also lets Francis escape because he was too focused on Wade.

Odds are he was going to find a way to restrain her and get her to HQ. Then he saw that Deadpool was going to kill Ajax and, being a goodie goodie boy scout, he instinctively went to stop Wade. While he was gone she regained consciousness assessed the situation and got the hell out of dodge. But that's just my opinion based on his previous actions and the events before that moment. In all honesty it could go either way.

Answer (score -1):

I hear that there will be Deadpool 2. Of course angel dust will be in that second movie. Why else was Colossus be seen carrying her along with negasonic teenage warhead. She most likely regained consciousness and took off.

Comment: Thank you for assisting the community. Ideas for framing an answer may include describing your sources along with a synopsis of what they said, adding links to the resources and visuals you’ve found, in addition to giving us the rationale behind your ideas and conclusions. I hope you enjoy participating.